# ' /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/lrelease: not found WARNING: TARGET is empty' Error when trying to compile Feathercoin from source

Tags: c++, compilation, qt4, makefile

I am following [this](http://forum.feathercoin.com/index.php/topic,430.msg3621.html#msg3621) tip on installing feathercoin from source. I have followed all the instructions up to:

```
qmake 'USE_UPNP=-`
make
```

That is where I get the following error:

```
1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/lrelease: not found
WARNING: TARGET is empty`
```

Below is the terminal output:

```
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_bg.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_ca_ES.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_cs.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_da.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_de.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_el_GR.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_en.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_es.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_es_CL.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_et.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_eu_ES.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_fa.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_fa_IR.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_fi.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_fr.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_fr_CA.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_he.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_hr.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_hu.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_it.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_lt.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_nb.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_nl.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_pl.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_pt_BR.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_pt_PT.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_ro_RO.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_ru.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_sk.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_sr.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_sv.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_tr.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_uk.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_zh_CN.qm'
RCC: Error in 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc': Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_zh_TW.qm'
```

As you may have guessed from the link I am using QT4 and I am using Ubuntu 13.04 32 bit OS. They all seem to be the same kind of error. If I can some way find a way to add the missing files 'locale/bitcoin_WHICHEVER.gm' to the relevant directory or find a way to point to directories they are in then my problem would be solved. Is there a way to fix this error, I figure once it is fixed then I can compile these various bits of software from source. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I did some fiddling about and found the file at 'src/qt/bitcoin.qrc' where I saw the 'locale/bitcoin_WHATEVER.qm' were actually some other extension other than '.qm' I renamed the files to reflect the '.qm' extension and that seemed to have fixed all the 'RCC: Errors' however, I still am getting the error `1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/lrelease: not found
WARNING: TARGET is empty`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I also faced both problems.

First (Cannot find file 'locale/bitcoin_WHICHEVER.qm') was solved my editing *src/qt/bitcoin.qrc* so that locale filenames to match existing files (replace *.qm* with *.ts* extension in references).

Second (*/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/lrelease: not found*) was solved by install of package **qttools5-dev-tools**:

```
sudo apt-get install qttools5-dev-tools
```

Now you can build witout UPnP support (qmake 'USE_UPNP=-`), but if you try to build default  config or with UPnP enabled, you'll get this error:

```
src/net.cpp:21:32: fatal error: miniupnpc/miniwget.h: No such file or directory
#include <miniupnpc/miniwget.h>
```

To solve it, install **libminiupnpc-dev** package:

```
sudo apt-get install libminiupnpc-dev
```

Comment: By the way, it's a problem of building an [old version](https://github.com/FeatherCoin/FeatherCoin) of Feathercoin client
Try to checkout [newer one](https://github.com/FeatherCoin/Feathercoin-0.8.5) and follow [it's build instructions](https://github.com/FeatherCoin/Feathercoin-0.8.5/blob/master-0.8/doc/readme-qt.rst), it has less build problems.